# C# - Find/Edit/Replace String

Tags: c#, replace, richtextbox, user-input, addition

I am trying to retrieve data from a file to change it and replace the old data.

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  10.505   -174.994 0  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  100.005  174.994  90  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  -10.000  -5.555   180  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  -500.987 5.123    270  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  987.123  1.000    180  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  234.567  200.999  90
```

I am trying to grab the **3rd and 4th columns** to change the data based on what a user inputs into two `TextBoxes`. Let's label the *3rd column* **"X"** and the *4th column* **"Y"**. With this, there are also **two** TextBoxes labeled **"xTextBox"** and **"yTextBox"**. These textboxes allow the user to enter in numbers and the number they enter in *(postive, negative, and/or a decimal up to 3 decimal places)* for each textbox (X and Y) will be **ADDED** to the "X" column values and the "Y" column values.

Right now, I am using this ***CODE*** (below) to strip the "X" and "Y" columns and display their values into different `RichTextBoxes` labeled **xRichTextBox** and **yRichTextBox**.

So, the ***xRichTextBox*** looks like this:

```
10.505
100.005
-10.000
-500.987
987.123
234.567
```

and the ***yRichTextBox*** looks like this:

```
-174.994
174.994
-5.555
5-123
1.000
200.999
```

---

***CODE:***

```
    private void calculateXAndYPlacementTwo()
    {
        // Reads the lines in the file to format.
        var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath);

        // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
        var fileList = new List<string>();

        // Adds each line in the file to the list.
        while (true)
        {
            var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            fileList.Add(line);
        }

        // Creates new lists to hold certain matches for each list.
        var xyResult = new List<string>();
        var xResult = new List<string>();
        var yResult = new List<string>();

        // Iterate over each line in the file and extract the x and y values
        fileList.ForEach(line =>
        {
            Match xyMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)");
            if (xyMatch.Success)
            {
                // grab the x and y values from the regular expression match
                String xValue = xyMatch.Groups["x"].Value;
                String yValue = xyMatch.Groups["y"].Value;

                // add these two values, separated by a space, to the "xyResult" list.
                xyResult.Add(String.Join(" ", new[]{ xValue, yValue }));

                // Adds the values into the xResult and yResult lists.
                xResult.Add(xValue);
                yResult.Add(yValue);

                // Place the 'X' and 'Y' values into the proper RTB.
                xRichTextBox.AppendText(xValue + "\n");
                yRichTextBox.AppendText(yValue + "\n");
            }
        });
    }
```

---

***SO*** for example if the user enters in **"10.005"** for the `xTextBox` and **"-20"** for the `yTextBox` the *updated* `xRichTextBox` would look like this:

```
20.510
110.010
0.005
-490.982
997.128
224.572
```

and the *updated* `yRichTextBox` would look like this:

```
-194.994
154.994
-25.555
-14.877
-19.000
180.999
```

---

After this takes place, I am trying to replace the **3rd and 4th columns** of the original file with the updated values.

- I am currently getting the values ("X" and "Y") in the file and outputting them to seperate `RichTextBoxes`, but I do not know how to add these values to the values entered in from each `TextBox`... How can I do this?
- After the `RichTextBox` values are calculated with the 'TextBox` values, how can I take these new values and add them to the **original** file?

**These values are not always the same or else I would hardcode them in.

---

So, the new file would look like this:

```
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  20.510   -194.994 0  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  110.010  154.994  90  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  0.005    -25.555  180  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  -490.982 -14.877  270  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  997.128  -19.000  180  
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  224.572  180.999  90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to read the files, but it sounds as though you're just putting them straight into the textboxes.  I would create an object to represent a line (with an x, y, and whatever the last column is).  When you read them in, create a list of the objects.  To display them, loop through and select each x (can easily be done with linq if you're using 4.0) and each y for the separate ones.  To update, loop through and add the appropriate number to each object.  Then to save, just write out each object again.

Edit: After looking more carefully at your code, you're keeping a list of the Xs, and a list of the Ys.  Create the object I mentioned and only keep a list of those.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a structured text file parser to parse and rewrite the file.

There is one in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace, the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx). This is a normal .NET assembly, so you *can* reference it in your code and use in from C#.

Answer (score 0):

before u save your date be sure to create string of data to be saved and than using textwriter or streamwriter save all content to the file again. I do not think u will be able to change only one portion of file and save it