# C# - Addition on a string and replace with new string

Tags: c#, string, replace, addition

If I have a `RichTextBox` that is loaded from a file containg:

```
TEXT MORETEXT 10.505  100.994 0  
TEXT MORETEXT -5.132  -12.994 90  
TEXT MORETEXT 100.001 -8.994  270
```

and a `TextBox` that contains whatever the user enters in the textbox. Let's say the user enters **"10.005"**.

**My question is**, how do I take this value and **add** it to the **3rd** column containing the values *10.505, -5.132, 100.001*. Once it is added, I would like to take the value and Replace the old value in the string. **SO** the updated `RichTextBox` would look like this.

```
TEXT MORETEXT 20.510  100.994 0  
TEXT MORETEXT 4.873  -12.994 90  
TEXT MORETEXT 110.006 -8.994  270
```

**RIGHT NOW** I am able to strip the strings from the `RichTextBox` by using this code:

```
    private void calculateXAndYPlacementTwo()
    {
        // Reads the lines in the file to format.
        var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath);

        // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
        var fileList = new List<string>();

        // Adds each line in the file to the list.
        while (true)
        {
            var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            fileList.Add(line);
        }

        // Creates new lists to hold certain matches for each list.
        var xyResult = new List<string>();
        var xResult = new List<string>();
        var yResult = new List<string>();

        // Iterate over each line in the file and extract the x and y values
        fileList.ForEach(line =>
        {
            Match xyMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)");
            if (xyMatch.Success)
            {
                // grab the x and y values from the regular expression match
                String xValue = xyMatch.Groups["x"].Value;
                String yValue = xyMatch.Groups["y"].Value;

                // add these two values, separated by a space, to the "xyResult" list.
                xyResult.Add(String.Join(" ", new[]{ xValue, yValue }));

                // Adds the values into the xResult and yResult lists.
                xResult.Add(xValue);
                yResult.Add(yValue);

                // Place the 'X' and 'Y' values into the proper RTB.
                xRichTextBox.AppendText(xValue + "\n");
                yRichTextBox.AppendText(yValue + "\n");
            }
        });
    }
```

To get the values in the **`xRichTextBox`** looking like:

```
10.505
-5.132
100.001
```

and the **`yRichTextBox`** looking like:

```
100.994
-12.994
-8.994
```

But I do not know how to turn those into values that can have *addition* used on them...

---

***EDIT:***
I have messed around with this some more... I am now using this code (below) to try to accomplish what I need it to do. This is only for the ***"X"*** *(3rd column)*.

### **HOWEVER THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING** (it concats the user input to the end of the `xRichTextBox` instead of mathematically adding it to each line..)

The `xDisplacementTextBox` is the user input and the `xRichTextBox` is the stripped values from the main string.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
string[] Lines = xRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
double d = double.Parse(xDisplacementTextBox.Text);

for(int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; ++i)
{
    string newThing = double.Parse((Lines[i]) + d).ToString();
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(newThing);
}

xRichTextBox.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

**This is also not letting me enter in values that have decimals (ie. 50.005)..**

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Find/Edit/Replace String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835689/c-find-edit-replace-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at double.Parse - as in 
    double x = double.Parse(xValue);

To expand, and do your work for you...

```
double d = double.Parse(xDisplacementTextBox.Text);
string[] Lines = xRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

for(int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; ++i)
{
    Match lineMatch = Regex.Match(lines[i], @"^(?<p>.*)(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)(?<y>\s+-?\d+\.\d+\s+-?\d+\.\d+)$");
    if (lineMatch.Success)
    {
        double xValue = double.Parse(lineMatch.Groups["x"].Value) + d;
        lines[i] = lineMatch.Groups["p"] + xValue + lineMatch.Groups["p"];
    }
 }
 xRichTextBox.Text = string.Join(lines, '\n');
```

Comment: I have updated my question above if you would care to take a look.

Comment: What is `double.Parse((Lines[i]) + d).ToString()` trying to achieve? As I understand it, Lines[i] will contain something like "TEXT MORETEXT 100.001 -8.994  270", which will cause double.Parse to throw an exception. You need to split the line up into the constituent parts, and parse the numbers individually.

Comment: I was trying to achieve adding the "d" to the "Lines[i]" and then `toString` it to output it back to the `RichTextBox`. For what you are saying to do, would I do a **foreach** loop? How would I do that?

Comment: I've expanded my answer - but I should point out that you would be far better doing this in a more object oriented way, as suggested by the other posters.

Answer (score 3):

**Too many strings and not enough data structures.**

This looks like a data structure:

TEXT MORETEXT 10.505  100.994 0
TEXT MORETEXT -5.132  -12.994 90
TEXT MORETEXT 100.001 -8.994  270

So, create a class that holds

```
"Text" string
"MoreText" string
10.505 - double (let's call this prop1)
100.994 - double
0 - int
```

I'm speculating on the data values here.

Load the List<> of your class into memory.

Then, apply the text box value to your list of object every time the value changes.

PsuedoCode:

```
foreach(class c in List<>)
    {
     c.prop1 = c.prop1 + (double)Textbox.value;
    }
```

Override `ToString()` in your class and display the object as needed in the rich text box.

Personally I would use a list box to display the objects.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, this seems very complex for me (as a beginner). Is there any way you could help talk me through what you are thinking?

Comment: I think you are close.  Read the file into your classes, manipulate the classes, then display on GUI.  Right now are reading the file and pushing the results right to the GUI which makes it hard to update since the data structure is just a string.

Comment: So I should remove the lines `xRichTextBox.AppendText(xValue + "\n");` and `yRichTextBox.AppendText(yValue + "\n");`? How could I replace them?

Comment: I updated my question above it you would care to take a look.

Comment: You need to carefully define a way of splitting each line of the file into its component parts (e.g. is "TEXT MORETEXT" a fixed length string? or two words? or any number of words, and terminated by the first number?). Create a class to hold the individual parts, and give it a constructor that takes a line of text and splits it up into the parts (doubles & strings). Also create a ToString method which builds a string from the parts. As you read the file, create items of this class from each line, and add them to the list. Then you can use simple addition on the parts, and re-render the result.